# Android: Center splash screen image

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have an app with a splash screen and the splash screen looks good on small devices but looks screwed up in a big tablet(emulator). so I changed the background to `wrap_content`. but it looks aligned to the side of the screen, Can some one tell me a way to center background images? here is my splash.xml-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't actually need neither `LinearLayout` nor `RelativeLayout` here, use a more lightweight `FrameLayout` instead.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 12):

I am using a background image for my activity. First create a theme in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Then create a new drawable with the name background_splash.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then set your activity to use this theme in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
```

This worked for me.

Comment: FYI, this is the right way to do it. Your background color stretches to match the screen size and then your logo will be centered on the screen without being distorted or skewed. Not sure what code errors @user924 is talking about but this example is what I followed and it worked well. I tweaked it a bit to get it just right on lots of different devices (old/new tablets, phones, etc.) but this formed a solid base to work from. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Slight change in code as it requires adding a second element for best fit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2A7800"<---- optional background color to fit the image. to make it blend in
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"<--- centers
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"<--- makes sure the image fits into the layout my matching the screen size.

        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adding an ImageView is best practice as it is better performance wise than using android:background and setting an image. I discovered this with a ScrollView and the master parent had android:background set to an image. It slowed down the ScrollView extremly.

Additionally, there is no need for a specific layout with this method. You can use RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, LinearLayout - anything that works. The exception might be ListView, GridView

Comment: If you have an image that isn't the same size as the screen, you can scale and center it nicely with `android:scaleType="centerInside"` instead of the `fixXY`

Answer (score 1):

Please try out the following

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it will not for different splash drawables

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative layout, try the below code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```